# Get clicked coordinates on rotated image

Tags: c#, image, win2d

I don't have a great concept on matrix math, so the other questions I have found have confused me, and I would like to know how to use Win2D-provided items to solve this issue.

I am creating a pixel art editor. I have an image, for simplicity sake, 2x2 pixels. In the editor, this image is scaled and rotated based on user interaction so that they may edit it. To make it rotate about it's center, I have also applied a translation. Here is my code to transform a 2x2 image into a rotated, scaled image which is rendered on the screen:

```
Matrix3x2 rotateMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)(Rotation * Math.PI / 180));
Matrix3x2 scaleMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(Scale);
Matrix3x2 translationMatrix = Matrix3x2.CreateTranslation(-(float)layer.Height / 2, -(float)layer.Width / 2);
Matrix3x2 transformation = translationMatrix * rotateMatrix * scaleMatrix;
```

This correctly draws my image on the screen. To allow the user to pan around the editor, there are also two additional translations happening with the rendered image, `OffsetX` and `OffsetY`, as seen here:

```
ICanvasImage image = new Transform2DEffect
{
    Source = source,
    TransformMatrix = transformation,
    InterpolationMode = CanvasImageInterpolation.NearestNeighbor
};
ctx.DrawImage(image, new Vector2(OffsetX, OffsetY));
```

So the rotated, scaled image is drawn at center `(OffsetX, OffsetY)`. All works fine.

Now I need to translate a screenspace click into an imagespace click. For example, if a user clicks the canvas at (300, 400), and the image is rotated and scaled and translated in such a way that the pixel at (0, 1) is under the cursor visually, I need to be able to translate (300, 400) into (0, 1).

Comment: Use the `Invert` method on the transformation matrix to get an inverse transformation. Then apply that to your clicked coordinates minus (OffsetX, OffsetY).

Comment: @RogerN being a matrix noob, how do I "apply" the coordinates to the matrix?

Comment: newVector = Vector2.Transform(oldVector, matrix)

Comment: @RogerN Wonderful! Please write out an answer so that I may accept it :)